# Xamarin.Forms VersionTracking not detecting first run ever

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I was using Xamarin.Forms VersionTracking for about a week now and everything was working fine, now I don't know why out of nowhere `IsFirstRunEver` isn't detecting first runs anymore when I uninstall the app and relaunch it like I was doing before it used to always detect first launch.

I used to have `VersionTracking.Track()` in the `OnStart` method of `App.xaml.cs` and

```
if (VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver)
{
    MainPage = new OnboardingPage();
}
```

in the constructor of `App.xaml.cs` but now even if I put `VersionTracking.Track()` in the constructor right after `InitializeComponents()` or in the `MainActivity`, `FirstRun` and every other first run detectors return `false`.

I couldn't even tell you what I've done for it to stop working, I have no clue and the output or debug don't tell me anything valuable.

I know it runs for the first time since it asks for the location permissions and all.

I'm reading the output and nothing indicates some kind of error.

Do you know where it could come from ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can set breakpoints to determine whether VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver has a value.

Comment: It has a false value which makes no sense and it gives me no more information

Comment: I mean you can add something like: var result = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver; check what it is exactly.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT I've done this and its returning false, that's why I can't explain why it's not working

Comment: You can use try/catch to view exception information.